# Where is the docker swarm token stored?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've created a docker-machine swarm cluster using a new generated token, which was stored within an environment variable. The environment variable was only for valid for the current session, and is deleted afterward.
Now I want to add a new docker-machine to the same cluster, but I can't find the needed token.

How is it possible to find out the token used by an active docker swarm ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Answering for posterity, since I had no luck with the other answer.

Running Docker 17.05.  Docker can now list join tokens for both workers and managers.

```
$ docker swarm join-token manager

To add a manager to this swarm, run the following command:

docker swarm join \
--token SWMTKN-1-13z9uafwgjdkfv3ik18ttceqgtogdqr4xurhc6vaybeckx7i7u-2lnnyzeqb93ejgjrdlivsg7rf \
10.0.0.18:2377



$ docker swarm join-token worker
To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

docker swarm join \
--token SWMTKN-1-13z9uafwgjdkfv3ik18ttceqgtogdqr4xurhc6vaybeckx7i7u-b3a28we1he23rxwk2rea933y4 \
10.0.0.18:2377
```

More information:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join-token/

Answer (score 2):

This article explains how this can be achieved:

[Getting the Docker Swarm Discovery Token](http://matthewkwilliams.com/index.php/2015/09/07/getting-the-docker-swarm-discovery-token/)

Execute: `docker inspect $SWARM_AGENT_MASTER` where `$SWARM_AGENT_MASTER` is the name of the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 2):

Just `ssh` into manager and get the tokens, like the following.

```
# get manager and worker tokens
 export MANAGER_TOKEN=`docker-machine ssh $SWARM_AGENT_MASTER "docker swarm join-token manager -q"`
 export WORKER_TOKEN=`docker-machine ssh $SWARM_AGENT_MASTER "docker swarm join-token worker -q"`
```